# Could not load file or assembly 'Prism.Forms' or one of its dependencies for Xamarin.Forms Portable

Tags: .net, mobile, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

After creating "**Prism ContentPage.Forms**" (*MainWindow*) and assigning it it to `Xamarin.Forms` app's Main Page I get this exception:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Prism.Forms' or one of its dependencies for Xamarin.Forms Portable

I tried updating every possible package, clean, rebuild ,re-install prism but nothing worked.

```
 public class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            // The root page of your application
            MainPage = new MainWindow();
        }....
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have installed the nugget packages into every project, not just the PCL.